# How do I save a macro with multiple commands with let?

Tags: vim

I'm currently learning to program in Vim, and I decided to make a macro to compile and run a C code quickly, so I made it like this:

```
save quickrun.c
!gcc quickrun.c -o quickrun
!quickrun
```

It worked as expected, no problems there, but then I tried to save the macro in the _vimrc file, and I had no problems with saving other macros with only one command using "let", like

```
let @a = '!gcc file.c'
```

But I want to save all the 3 commands in order to compile and run in the macro, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Macros are like replayable keystrokes: they are as if you typed them. So if you want to use the ex command `:!`, you need to start with a colon. Then you can use the `|`:

```
let @a = ":save ... | !gcc ... \<CR> !quickrun\<CR>"
```

A better solution is a mapping:

```
nnoremap keys execute ":save ... <bar> !gcc ... <bar> !quickrun<CR>"
```

But for C code you can usually just use `:make`

Comment: To insert a `<cr>`, you can use a double quoted string and then use "\<cr>" or "\r". My suggestion would be `let @a = ":save ...\<cr>:!gcc ...\<cr>:!quickrun\<cr>"`

Comment: E15: Invalid expression: "\<cr>"

Comment: Hm, in the mapping I don't think the `\` is needed anymore (because `:map` interprets special keys)

Answer (score 3):

That's a very strange idea to put a sequence of commands into a register *permanently*. Typically, one uses a register to build commands on-the-fly by yanking portions of code from some script, or by recording a key sequence with `q`. The problem is that you have only 26 slots with fixed names, and that's quite inconvenient for storing general command sequences.

More frequent solution is to setup user commands or mappings (or both). You can define a command (it must start with a capital letter!) in your vimrc like this:

```
command! QRun save quickrun.c | !gcc quickrun.c -o quickrun | !quickrun
```

The bar symbol (|) is a command separator in Vim script, i.e. it's allowed in an interactive mode too. After that you can execute your command just like everything else: `:QRun`. If you feel "QRun" is too hard to type, you can additionally define a key mapping to spare a couple of keystrokes.

Also, you probably should revise your script to use arguments, and to get rid of "save[as]" in favour of plain "update", and so on.